# Keep value in input box when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to keep the value from a input box even when the page is refreshed.

I know that i could do that using just an echo, but i'm connecting two different files.

I have one page with the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="mypage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="test">
<input type"submit">
</form>
```

And another one(mypage.php) that reads the form

```
<input type="text" name="value" value='<?php echo $_POST['value']; ?>' />
```

The code is working, bue lets imagine that someone refreshed the page and the value desappears.

I want to know how can I keep the value inside the textbox even when someone refreshes the page.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a `$_SESSION` http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: 1. Read the value of the `<input>` element when it is changed (using javascript and `onchange` on the `<input>` element)
2. Save that value using cookies or local storage.
3. When loading the page, read that value from cookies or local storage and set the `<input>` value to that.

Comment: relentless: I *think* he wants it to work even if the form is not submitted... in which case, PHP would not know the new value if the page is reloaded.

Comment: @HamzaKubba Prefer `sessionStorage` over `localStorage` or cookies. `sessionStorage` will only apply to the current tab (useful if you're filling the form out on several tabs), and cookies are needlessly sent to the server.

Comment: Agree that cookies are lame-ish... though he may want to check the value and overwrite it on the server, in which case he'd want cookies (or ajax)... depends on the use case... there are many solutions anyway, pick the one that works best for you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a session to preserve the value:

```
<?php
session_start();
if((isset($_SESSION["preserve"]))&&($_SESSION["preserve"] != "")){
    $_SESSION["preserve"] = $_POST['value'];
}else{
    $_SESSION["preserve"] = "";
}
?>

<input type="text" name="value" value='<?php echo $_SESSION["preserve"]; ?>' />

<?php 
//when you don't need this session anymore do this:
//(that can also be called in another page of your project)
unset($_SESSION["preserve"]);
?>
```

Hope that's what you were looking for...

Comment: This will generate an error (or perhaps just a warning) if you hit the page without posting the expected value. You need to check that the post value is set and if not default the session value to an empty string. I've edited the answer for you :)

Comment: My bad nettux! Due perhaps to late hour here in Greece!... I 've approved your edit and hopefully that will be the answer @user3610021 was looking for!

Comment: you're missing a closing } (not a big enough edit for me to suggest) after the else. personally I'd prefer ternary operator for something this short.

Comment: @nettux443 You are now my official debugger!!! Congrats on your sharp ability of observation... Just corrected that too... Thank you :)